# why audio don't work in html 5 using gingerbread android in eclipse

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-audio

I have tried to do work on playing an audio file (i tried .wav and .mp3 format) using html5 sudio tags. But when run the project on the simulator in eclipse for android Gingerbread it does not seem to play when I click on my play button that I created. I am using android 4.0 API. Why is this so? Am I missing out on anything that prevent the simulator from playing the tone?

Below is my html code:

```
$('#page-home').live('pageinit', function(event){  
    $('.api-div').hide();
    $('.api-div#api-intro').show();

    $('#intro').click(function() {
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $('.api-div#api-intro').show();
        $.mobile.silentScroll(0);            
    });

    $('div ul li a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('clicked : ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        var attrId = $(this).attr('id');

        if (attrId.indexOf("click") !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        var api = '#api' + attrId.substring(attrId.indexOf('-'));

        // hide all div's, show only this one
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $(api).show();

        // if small screen and portrait - close after tap
        var disp = $('ul #listdivider').css("display");
        //alert(disp + ' : ' + api);
        if (disp === 'none') {
            $('div.ui-collapsible').trigger("collapse");
        } else {
            $.mobile.silentScroll(0);            
        }
    }); 

    $('#listdivider').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $('.api-div#api-intro').show();
        $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    });

    $("#playaudio").live('tap', function() {
        var src = 'tone1K.mp3';
        // Note: two ways to access media file: web and local file        
        //var src = 'http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3';

        // local (on device): copy file to project's /assets folder:
        // var src = '/android_asset/spittinggames.m4a';

        playAudio(src);
    });

    $("#pauseaudio").live('tap', function() {
        pauseAudio();
    });

    $("#stopaudio").live('tap', function() {
        stopAudio();
    });


});
```

Below is my javascript for playing the tone on click:

```
$('#page-home').live('pageinit', function(event){  
    $('.api-div').hide();
    $('.api-div#api-intro').show();

    $('#intro').click(function() {
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $('.api-div#api-intro').show();
        $.mobile.silentScroll(0);            
    });

    $('div ul li a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('clicked : ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        var attrId = $(this).attr('id');

        if (attrId.indexOf("click") !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        var api = '#api' + attrId.substring(attrId.indexOf('-'));

        // hide all div's, show only this one
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $(api).show();

        // if small screen and portrait - close after tap
        var disp = $('ul #listdivider').css("display");
        //alert(disp + ' : ' + api);
        if (disp === 'none') {
            $('div.ui-collapsible').trigger("collapse");
        } else {
            $.mobile.silentScroll(0);            
        }
    }); 

    $('#listdivider').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.api-div').hide();
        $('.api-div#api-intro').show();
        $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    });

    $("#playaudio").live('tap', function() {
        var src = 'tone1K.mp3';
        // Note: two ways to access media file: web and local file        
        //var src = 'http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3';

        // local (on device): copy file to project's /assets folder:
        // var src = '/android_asset/spittinggames.m4a';

        playAudio(src);
    });

    $("#pauseaudio").live('tap', function() {
        pauseAudio();
    });

    $("#stopaudio").live('tap', function() {
        stopAudio();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with WebM audio. Google added WebM supported in Android 2.3 Gingerbread. A lot of people have trouble with `<audio>` in Android 2.2.

Comment: how do i go about using the WebM? Any software or sample codes available?

Comment: and is WebM compatible for use on iphone and other platforms?

Comment: [List of non-commercial tools](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/#non-commercial-webm-tools) and [list of non-commercial tools](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/#commercial-webm-tools). You can't use WebM on iOS, so try with `.ogg` (your quiestion is about Android 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to include the mp3 file that you have specified?

did you try this in a real device? I don't know if there is any issue with emulator for this. Did't try audio with emulator. It should work in it I think.

Anyways for your problem what i would recommend is to use [phonegap media api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are running into this bug that Google hasn't fixed yet:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10546

In the meantime that is why we have the Media API:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar troubles in Gingerbread (2.3.6) but came across this test page:
http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/

Which was working fine in 2.3.6 whereas my original code (that worked fine elsewhere) did not. Looking at the JS on this page, there were a few things happening that I wasn't doing. This is where I netted out:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#play').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var mediaObj = $('#audioMeme').get(0);
        $('#audioMeme').attr('src','bounce.mp3');
        mediaObj.pause()
        mediaObj.currentSrc = 'bounce.mp3';
        mediaObj.load();
        playAudio();

        function playAudio(){
            var audioReady = mediaObj.readyState;
            if(mediaObj.error) {
                alert('no dice');
            }
            if(audioReady>2) {
                mediaObj.play();
            }
            else{
                setTimeout(play,500);                   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="audioMeme" autoplay preload="auto" loop src="">
<source src="bounce.mp3">
</audio>

<a href="#" id="play">play</a>
```

And now it's all good in 2.3.6.